# Why does this thread keep running when app is in background?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around android services. I thought that you'd need them to run some kind of task in the background, e.g. when the app is closed. Now I've created a simple application that will start a thread (not a service!) when a button is clicked. I assumed that the thread would stop operating as soon as the app is minimized. However, it keeps running when minimized. What am I missing here?

This is how the thread is created/started when the UI-button is clicked:

```
fab.setOnClickListener {
    val t = Thread {
        while (true) {
            Log.i("MyServiceExample", "Thread running in MainActivity")
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
    }
    t.start()
}
```

Comment: It happens as it is because Thread is not lifecycle aware, so it doesnt know when a fragment or activity in onPause, onDestroy. I highly recommend that you manually stop it onPause/OnDestroy.. 
I dont know exactly what you are aiming but you can use coroutine/viewmodel to solve the lifecycle awareness issue.

Comment: Thanks. This is just a toy-example. My assumption was that work would stop when the app is minimized and that you would need a service to keep running a task when minimized. This simple example disproves this which makes me question what you'd need e.g. the IntentService for when you can just spawn a simple thread.

Comment: Issue is that you cant rely on ur Thread to keep going as long as you want, as the AndroidOS can kill if needed and you do not have control over it. Also if you let it run forever it will drain users battery.

Comment: Alright, I think I got it now. As suggest by you, *have* to clean up your thread by using the lifecycle-callbacks (e.g. onCreate(), onDestroy()). In my example the thread will leak, e.g. not be collected by the GC since threads are GC-roots. Anyway, I think I've got it. Thanks for helping!